# DataGridView Remove Ability For User To Add New Row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

At the bottom of a DataGridView, there appears to be an empty row for the user to fill out  if he/she wants to add another row.  Is it possible to remove this feature from the DataGridViews I create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) to `false`

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows=False`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property or if you use DataView you can do fallowing:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
dataView.AllowNew = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource=dataView;
```

There are also other properties you can control in `DataView`: `AllowEdit`, `AllowDelete`